# Socket code from python to Objective C

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, cocoa, sockets

I need some help to translate this code from Python to Objective C (for iOS).

I know how to create the socket in C but perhaps ther is a most elegant way to do it with cocoa classes (NSStream ?)

What is the equivalent of thats chr(0x00) and b64encode ?

if you guys have some knowledge in Python And Objective, thank you for your help !

```
new = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
new.connect((dst, 55000))

msg = chr(0x64) + chr(0x00) +\
    chr(len(base64.b64encode(src)))    + chr(0x00) + base64.b64encode(src) +\
    chr(len(base64.b64encode(mac)))    + chr(0x00) + base64.b64encode(mac) +\
    chr(len(base64.b64encode(remote))) + chr(0x00) + base64.b64encode(remote)

pkt = chr(0x00) +\
    chr(len(app)) + chr(0x00) + app +\
    chr(len(msg)) + chr(0x00) + msg
new.send(pkt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is a working translation. It certainly can be improved and your comments are welcome but it works fine and does exactly what the Python code did.

```
NSString * src = @"X.X.X.X";
NSString * mac = @"XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX";


const unsigned char byte64[] = {0x64};
const unsigned char byte00[] = {0x00};

NSString * srcString = [src base64EncodedString];
int srcDataLength = [srcString length];
char* srcDataLengthAsByte = (char*) &srcDataLength;

NSString * macString = [mac base64EncodedString];
int macDataLength = [macString length];
char* macDataLengthAsByte = (char*) &macDataLength;

NSString * remoteString = [remote base64EncodedString];
int remoteDataLength = [remoteString length];
char* remoteDataLengthAsByte = (char*) &remoteDataLength;

NSString * appString = [app base64EncodedString];
int appDataLength = [appString length];
char* appDataLengthAsByte = (char*) &appDataLength;

NSMutableData * msgData = [NSMutableData data];
[msgData appendBytes:byte64 length:1];
[msgData appendBytes:byte00 length:1];
[msgData appendBytes:srcDataLengthAsByte length:1];
[msgData appendBytes:byte00 length:1];
[msgData appendData:[srcString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[msgData appendBytes:macDataLengthAsByte length:1];
[msgData appendBytes:byte00 length:1];
[msgData appendData:[macString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[msgData appendBytes:remoteDataLengthAsByte length:1];
[msgData appendBytes:byte00 length:1];
[msgData appendData:[remoteString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
int msgDataLength = [msgData length];
char* msgDataLengthAsByte = (char*) &msgDataLength;

NSMutableData * packet = [NSMutableData data];
[packet appendBytes:byte00 length:1];
[packet appendBytes:appDataLengthAsByte length:1];
[packet appendBytes:byte00 length:1];
[packet appendData:[appString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[packet appendBytes:msgDataLengthAsByte length:1];
[packet appendBytes:byte00 length:1];
[packet appendData:msgData];
[self send:packet];
```

And the socket part :

```
- (BOOL)connect
{
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    sockfd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr([TV_IP UTF8String]);
    addr.sin_port = htons(TV_PORT);
    return connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr))==0;
}

- (long)send:(NSData*)data
{
    long sent = send(sockfd, [data bytes], [data length], 0);

    VADebugLog(@"sent data:(%ld bytes) = [%@]",sent,[data description]);

    return sent;
}

-(void)close
{
    close(sockfd);
}
```

And the include with base64 from :  https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#import "Base64.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer. It does not address your question about sockets as that is an area I have no experience in when it comes to objective-c

As for your other two questions:

**What is the equivalent of `chr(0x00)`?**

The equivalent of `chr(0x<num>)` is simply `'0xnum'`. So for example `chr(0x00)` becomes `'0x00'`. Note that it is important that you use single quotes and not double quotes here as unlike in python in C/objective-c they have different meanings

**What is the equivalent of b64encode?**

Well, it doesn't seem like there's a way to do this out of the box as is the case with python. However, there's an [entry for this on the SO wiki](http://stackoverflow.org/wiki/Base64_Encoding/Decoding_in_Objective-C) which points to [this article](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html). The article has a link for some source code at the end which you should be able to use as-is. It works by using categories to add methods to `NSData` which will allow you to encode/decode base64 strings.

Comment: OK Thank you. I wrote the begining of the translation in my original Question. Do you think it looks good ? I thought there is a better way to write this peace of code...

Comment: I don't think that `'0x00'` is what you want. Do you mean `'\x00'` perhaps? Or just `0x00` without the quotes?

Comment: I tried it with gcc and it works in C, which means it should work for objc.